# Does Apache thrift work with Scala

Tags: scala, thrift

I am new to apache thrift and I am familiar with Scala. But I have not seen any example or any reference on internet, saying it supports Scala.
Can some one tell me is there a way to work with scala on thrif. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, thrift can work with scala smoothly. It's not surprising since scala essentially works on JVM. One open-source example is Twitter's Scalding, a scala DSL for Cascading. In scalding, one is able to handle various cascading flows whose tuples are in the type of thrift-based classes.
See [LongThriftTransformer](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/develop/scalding-commons/src/main/scala/com/twitter/scalding/commons/source/LongThriftTransformer.scala) for example.

Comment: I cannot think of a public available example off the top of my head. But you can use scala with thrift almost the same way as what you do in java,. So as long as you set up your BUILD file correctly with thrift dependency. It can automatically generate the class for you. See this Build file for example: https://github.com/twitter/scalding/blob/develop/project/Build.scala#L205

Answer (score 2):

I don't mean to be rude, but **the very first link** for the google query [*apache thrift scala*](http://bit.ly/1jz9aQe) shows up [scrooge](https://github.com/twitter/scrooge), which

1. notes, that due to interoperability between scala and java ordinary thrift-java will work fine
2. itself -- a way to work with thrift in scala-native way

So yes, there are ways to work with Thrift in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Twitters '[Scrooge](https://twitter.github.io/scrooge/)' is meant as a replacement for the standard Thrift generator and generates Java and Scala code. It works with SBT and seems relatively mature.